# Limit Google Ads to particular blog posts

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, testing, adsense

I want to introduce Google Ads on my website. But to start on I want to do it only on a particular blog post. It is part of some real-time testing that I need to do. I want to use Google AdSense plugin.

E.g. I have 3 blog posts.

`www.exampleblog.com/abc`

`www.exampleblog.com/pqr`

`www.exampleblog.com/xyz`

I want to place ads
on the right on `www.exampleblog.com/abc`
on the left on `www.exampleblog.com/pqr`
no ads on `www.exampleblog.com/xyz`

Just now I am not able to test it as I want the confirmation that Google Adsense plugin for WordPress allows this customization.
There is an option to decide advertisement placement for 'Single Post'. How does that work?
[image: Options]

Alternative ways apart from using Google AdSense are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, Google Adsense is just a script that you insert somewhere in your html. If your theme is well widgetized, there are plenty of places where you could insert the script using the default text widget. To hide/show the widget on specific pages you could use a visibility widget (plenty of choice) that lets you specify the conditions.

If your theme doesn't have a widget area in the place where you would like insert the ad, you could build a child theme that inserts one in the appropriate place, for instance by hooking into the featured image and display the ad after it, depending on certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Widgets only allow visibility customization up till page type only i.e. if you want to limit widgets to only category page or post page in general. It does not allow to target the a particular post or category like I asked for.

Comment: @HBalyan Yes, with the standard jetpack widget visibility. There are other plugins. Try one of these, for instance: http://www.wpsolver.com/how-to-hide-and-control-wordpress-widgets-5-plugins/